# module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'Owner'

Tags: django

this the models.py. the car class was left out because it was not needed to save reading but its there

```
class Owner(models.Model):


carID = models.ForeignKey(Car)    
Owner_Entry_Number = models.IntegerField()
Owner_Date = models.DateField('Proprietor start date', null=True, blank=True)

Owner_Last_Name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
Owner_First_Name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
Owner_Middle_Initial = models.CharField(max_length=6, null=True, blank=True)
Owner_Address = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True, blank=True)
```

my view

```
from .models import Car, Owner
from django.db import models
def switchingowners(request):
ownersofcar = Owner.objects.filter(CarID = request.user['CarID'])
for owner in ownersofcar :
                addingOwner = models.Owner(CarID=form['CarID'],
                    )
```

basically it fails to work 
now i know it kinda confusing but basically all the owners of a car  i want to transfer them to a new car or cars
but  i get

```
      module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'Owner'
```

because of this line

```
addingOwner = models.Owner(CarID=form['CarID'],
```

but i have the imports and dont know why

using django 1.8

Comment: remove the `models.` from the second to last line in your view

Comment: thanks man i saw an example online stating that models. was needed
it was such a simple problem now im getting a type error but i think i can solve the rest!
and i think type error means the wrong data into the wrong field 
like a string into a int